# Site Load Slow + why does Minify CSS take so long to download

Tags: css, minify, pagespeed

[image]

Above is an image from Chrome Network that shows the site www.hot-girl.co (excuse the domain name - its only temp) downloading images.

If you can see the image the minified CSS is only 20K (down from 100K) but it takes 5 seconds to download and I don't understand why.

The Server is with AWS Amazon and running Nginx and the CSS is on the server.

Is there any ideas why this would take 5 seconds? I can provide more information if needed.

thankyou

Comment: I've had a similar issue a while ago, and the problem was a piece of C# code (ASP.NET) that was delaying the JS file to be downloaded. Maybe?

Comment: It's not actually taking 5 seconds to download, it's latency. The server is taking almost 5 seconds to respond, downloading is only a fraction of the time. I don't know why but just thought I'd point that out :)